TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' in array to set
in this def i get TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' in line retrieved_indices_set = set(retrieved_indices)
def evaluate_retrieval(query_idx, retrieved_indices, relevant_indices):
    # Convert each list element to a tuple
    # Flatten the two-layer list and convert elements to tuples
    arr = np.array(retrieved_indices) #retrieved_indices => 128 * 128 * 3

# Transpose the array and convert it to a list of tuples
    retrieved_indices = tuple(list(map(tuple, np.vstack(arr.T))))
    print(type(retrieved_indices))

# Create a set from the tuples
    retrieved_indices_set = set(retrieved_indices)
    relevant_retrieved = len(retrieved_indices_set.intersection(relevant_indices_set))
    precision = relevant_retrieved / len(retrieved_indices_set) if len(retrieved_indices_set) > 0 else 0
    return precision

I try this but didn't work
retrieved_indices_tuples = tuple(tuple(tuple(pixel) for pixel in row) for row in retrieved_indices)


Python doesn't let numpy arrays be elements of sets or keys of hash tables.  For the same reason it doesn't allow dictionaries or lists to be elements of sets or keys of hash tables.  These are mutable objects.  If you need a key, make something completely immutable.

I solved this problem in this way:
retrieved_indices_tuples = tuple(
    tuple(
        tuple(
            tuple(pixel) for pixel in slice
        ) for slice in row
    ) for row in retrieved_indices
)
    print(type(retrieved_indices_tuples))  # Should print <class 'tuple'>
    print(type(retrieved_indices_tuples[0]))  # Should print <class 'tuple'>
    print(type(retrieved_indices_tuples[0][0]))  # Should print <class 'tuple'>
    print(type(retrieved_indices_tuples[0][0][0]))  # Should print <class 'tuple'>
    print(type(retrieved_indices_tuples[0][0][0][0])) # Should print <class 'int'>


It's impossible to convert numpy.ndarray elements directly into a set.
You need to convert the numpy.ndarray to a hashable type such as a tuple.
Something like this:
import numpy as np

def evaluate_retrieval(query_idx, retrieved_indices, relevant_indices):
    retrieved_indices_tuples = tuple(tuple(tuple(pixel) for pixel in row) for row in retrieved_indices)
    
    retrieved_indices_set = set(retrieved_indices_tuples)
    
    relevant_indices_set = set(relevant_indices)
    
    # Calculate the intersection of the sets
    relevant_retrieved = len(retrieved_indices_set.intersection(relevant_indices_set))
    
    precision = relevant_retrieved / len(retrieved_indices_set) if len(retrieved_indices_set) > 0 else 0
    
    return precision

retrieved_indices = np.random.randint(0, 256, (128, 128, 3))  # Sample data
relevant_indices = [((0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2))]  # Sample relevant indices

precision = evaluate_retrieval(0, retrieved_indices, relevant_indices)
print(f"Precision: {precision}")

